# Capability of using usb wifi adapter with linuxserver/webtop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, webtop

I do not know if it is possible but I would like to use a usb wifi adapter with [webtop](https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-webtop). Unfortunately I did not find anything relevant, no matter how much I searched.